# using django-tables2 in dashbord

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tables2

Trying to put django table into dashboard.html page. I can visualize my table in another html file but cant fix how to put inside the dashboard page

models.py

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(AssetType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lc_phase = models.ForeignKey("Asset_Life_Cycle.LifeCyclePhase", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # BaseSpatialField.srid()
    geom = models.GeometryField()
```

views.py

```
from .models import Asset
import django_tables2 as tables



class AssetTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta :
        model = Asset

class AssetTableView(tables.SingleTableView):

    queryset = Asset.objects.all()
    table_class = AssetTable
    template_name = 'deneme.html'
```

Tried this but didnt work

```
{% for asset in queryset %}

    <p>Name {{asset.name}} </span> </p>

  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of django-tables2 is that you don't need to loop over all objects in your queryset. Just use the following code in your template which will display the table:

```html
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% render_table table %}
```